# How to run the program like ./main.py --fields column1, column2

Tags: python

I have

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)
data_json = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

In `df` different columns which user can select in the terminal by running the code `./main.py --fields column1, column2`. I understand that I sould use `argparse` library. But the methods I have tried didn't worth my effort.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work for me:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process rows to display.')
parser.add_argument('--fields', type=str, help='Rows to display')

args = parser.parse_args()
select = args.select.split(',') if args.select else None
```

df contain :

```
date                 column1  column2     column3   column4 
0   2022-01-01          1     2.550000  Unknown  facebook
1   2022-01-01          5     2.470000  Unknown  facebook
2   2022-01-01          2     2.620000  Unknown  facebook
3   2022-01-01          3     2.480000  Unknown  facebook
4   2022-01-01          2     2.440000  Unknown  facebook
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO
import hashlib
import time
import argparse
import sys


def get_file():
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zLdEcpzCp357s3Rse112Lch9EMUWzMLE/view?usp=sharing'
    file_id = url.split('/')[-2]
    dwn_url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id
    url2 = requests.get(dwn_url).text
    csv_raw = StringIO(url2)
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)
    data_json = df.to_json(orient='records')
    df.drop(5, inplace=True)

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        select = sys.argv[1:]
    else:
        select = 'None'

    print(df[select])


def make_table():
    pd.options.display.width = 500
    pd.options.display.width = None  # for unlimited
    pd.options.display.max_columns = 50
    pd.options.display.max_columns = None  # for unlimited
    pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 30
    pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None  # for unlimited


def calculate_hash(df):
    df_str = df.to_string().encode()
    hash = hashlib.sha256(df_str).hexdigest()
    return hash

def monitor_file(interval):
    previous_hash = None
    while True:
        df, data_json = get_file()
        current_hash = calculate_hash(df)
        if previous_hash != current_hash:
            print("File has been updated")
            print(df.head(50))
            print(data_json)
        previous_hash = current_hash
        time.sleep(interval)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor_file(120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    select = sys.argv[1:]
else:
    select = 'None'

print(select)
```

will output:

`Python myFile.py lorem ipsum`

```
['lorem','ipsum']
```

`python myFile.py`

```
None
```

then to get them as fields in your dataframe:

```
df[select]
```

for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lorem':[1,2,3],'ipsum':['a','b','c']})

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    select = sys.argv[1:]
else:
    select = 'None'

print(df1[select])
```

`python myFile.py lorem ipsum`

returns:

```
   lorem ipsum
0      1     a
1      2     b
2      3     c
```

Comment: yes, it works when you have array, but I sould get the columns from DataFrame

Comment: i have posted what df contain

Comment: if its still not working, send the code to create your dataframe and I will test :)

Comment: i have the error `AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: you'll have to send the code causing that if you want it to be reproduced

Comment: I have pinned my all code in the question, can you check?

Comment: that error is outside of the scope of the initial questions, but looks to be caused by one of your imports, argparse for example. you need to check whats actually causing that error, but as I say its a separate question. Hope I've helped

Answer (score 1):

With `argparse` you have three options:

1. Ditch the space after comma (`--fields column1,_column2`) and split the string like you did

   ```
   --fields column1,column2
   ```
2. Use [`nargs='+'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

   ```
   --fields column1 column2
   ```
3. Use [`action='append'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)

   ```
   --field column1 --field column2
   ```

Either way, you get a list of strings for `args.fields` (or `select` in p. 1 and your code).  I would personally go for option 2 (`nargs='+'`)